# Getting wrong output for subtraction of columns in two tables in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, Deposit table and Withdraw. These two tables have a same column "game_name" which is foreign key to the Game table.

| Game |
| --- |
| game_name |

| Deposit |
| --- |
| game_name |
| d_amount |
| d_bonus |

| Withdraw |
| --- |
| game_name |
| w_amount |

Sample data:

**Deposit**

```
[GameName] [d_amount] [d_bonus]
-------------------------------
  Mario       100        10
  Mario       200        20
  Mario       300        30
```

**Withdraw**

```
[GameName] [w_amount] 
----------------------
  Mario       30        
  Mario       50
```

**Desire output :**  (100+200+300+10+20+30) - (30+50) = 580

I need to write a sql statement to calculate the total credit of the game, **(SUM of d.amount+d.bonus) - (SUM of w.amount)** and that will be the total credit for the game Mario.

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT SUM(deposit.d_amount+deposit.d_bonus) - SUM(withdraw.w_amount) from deposit 
cross join withdraw 
where deposit.game_name and withdraw.game_name = "Mario";
```

I'm getting the wrong output.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done edited the sample data and desired results, please help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select game_name,
       sum(amount + bonus - w_amount)
from ((select d.game_name, d.amount, d.bonus, 0 as w_amount
       from deposits d
      ) union all
      (select w.game_name, w.amount, 0 as bonus, 0 w.w_amount
       from withdraw w
      )
     ) dw
group by d.game_name;
```

Note:  This includes all `game_name`, even those that are in only one table.

Second, this assumes that the values in the columns are not `NULL`.  If that is possible, then use `COALESCE()`.